# Gradient color under Line Chart

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

[I want to create this kind of color under a line chart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9i9a.png)

I searched for a solution but can't find one that uses react-chart-js2. I want to do this without using the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this should work very easy out-of-the-box (no plugin needed), you just need to set the `backgroundColor` property to a function, that outputs a gradient. (And set the `fill`property to the desired values).

Although, I can't say how you would have to integrate this with `react`, this is plain chartjs.

**Here a demo, how I would do this:**
*(based on this [official example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/advanced/linear-gradient.html) )*
The function for the gradient `getGradient` was taken from the above mentioned example.

```js
const lineChartData = {
    labels: [
      '01/22',
      '02/22',
      '03/22',
      '04/22',
      '05/22',
      '06/22',
      '07/22',
      '08/22',
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Profit',
        data: [2.4, 2.6, 2.23, 1.2, -2.2, -3.6, -1, 0.2],
        borderColor: '#0B9564',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
        pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
        borderJoinStyle: 'bevel',
        // the following 2 properties are the ones that need to be set
        fill: {
            value: -25,
        },
        backgroundColor: (context) => {
          const chart = context.chart;
          const {ctx, chartArea} = chart;
          if (!chartArea) {
            // This case happens on initial chart load
            return;
          }
          return getGradient(ctx, chartArea);
        },
      },
    ],
  };

let width, height, gradient;

function getGradient(ctx, chartArea) {
  const chartWidth = chartArea.right - chartArea.left;
  const chartHeight = chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top;
  if (!gradient || width !== chartWidth || height !== chartHeight) {
    // Create the gradient because this is either the first render
    // or the size of the chart has changed
    width = chartWidth;
    height = chartHeight;
    gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, chartArea.bottom, 0, chartArea.top);
    gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,128, 0, 1)');
    gradient.addColorStop(.25, 'rgba(0,128, 0, 0)');
  }
  return gradient;
}
const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: lineChartData,
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                position: 'right',
                labels: {
                    usePointStyle: true,
                },
            }
        },
    }
};

var myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('chart'),
    config
);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>  

<div class="chart" style="height:184px; width:350px;">
    <canvas  id="chart" ></canvas>
</div>
```

> **Checkout:** the documentation for details on the [color properties / features](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html) and the [line Chart properties](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html)